# NFC Android To Check Device's Apps

Tags: android, nfc

This may be the wrong place to post this but I was wondering if there was a way to use NFC to check what apps the other device has installed.
For example, I want to send data to another device and store it in a specific folder if they have the same app installed, but if they don't, I want to store it in a different location.

Comment: You don't "store it" anywhere, any more than the sender of an email dictates what folder it goes into on the recipient's mail client. Using things like Android Beam, you can send files to another device using NFC and Bluetooth, but it is the *recipient* that determines where the content goes, not the sender.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, okay. That makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @arkdevelopment mark answer as accepted instead of changing title.

Answer (score 1):

No.  How would that even work?  You'd need to have an app on the phone to get the NFC data, understand what it is, and put it in the correct folder.  Which means you'd need to have an app on the device to do all that.